# DateTime.Now.Ticks is too slow

Tags: c#

I am making a password generator which can generate a password.

```
 var listOfCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" //the chars which are using
    chars = listOfCharacters.ToCharArray();

  string password = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
                int x = random.Next(0, chars.Length); //with random he is picking a random char from my list from position 0 - 26 (a - z)

                 password += chars.GetValue(x); // putting x (the char which is picked) in the new generated password

            }
            if (length < password.Length) password = password.Substring(0, length); // if the password contains the correct length he will be returns


            return password;
```

My random:

```
random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

I am looking for a faster way to generate a password than using Ticks, because its not fast enough for me. I am looking for a simple code which i can easy put in my above code. I am just a beginner in C#.  So that i still can use  `int x = random.Next(0, chars.Length);` but instead of `Random.next` a faster one.

EDIT:
When i want two generate two passwords in a short time .Ticks is to slow

My test code:

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void PasswordGeneratorShouldRenderUniqueNextPassword()
    {
        // Create an instance, and generate two passwords
        var generator = new PasswordGenerator();
        var firstPassword = generator.Generate(8); //8 is the length of the password
        var secondPassword = generator.Generate(8);

        // Verify that both passwords are unique
        Assert.AreNotEqual(firstPassword, secondPassword);
    }
```

Comment: There are much stronger, better performing random password generation methods out there. Is there a reason you're not going with something pre-built instead of rolling your own?

Comment: How do you determine that DateTime.Now.Ticks is "too slow"? How fast is fast enough?

Comment: `Random` uses ticks internally if constructed without a seed parameter.

Comment: Don't create always new random instances but reuse one. That's also the only way to ensure that you get "random" values.

Comment: When i am going with something pre-built instead of my own i needs to edit my whole code because i am almost finish with my app but only needs to fix this problem

Comment: Why is speed such an issue for you?

Comment: @dtb as I understand, ticks updated every 16 ms, that will give same seed for two consequent calls

Comment: @dtb i need to generate multiple passwords in less than 1 ms

Comment: But you use Ticks only once during app lifetime, so it should not matter

Comment: How useful is a sequence of passwords if all of them can be regenerated when someone knows the seed/the time at which they were generated? Your algorithm is flawed.

Comment: You could build a very long string with a random sequence of letters and then retrieve chunks of the desired `length` when you call the function.

Comment: The fact that you're using += to build up the string instead of a StringBuilder says to me you don't need to concern yourself about the speed of DateTime.Now.Ticks just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the hashcode of a [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) as seed value for your Random instance. It should be random enough for your case.

```
random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working for me. Coulf you maybe give a little summary of this code? So what it exactly is meaning

Answer (score 0):

Either create the `Random` instance once at startup or use the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

```
// Create the random instance only once.
private static Random _Random = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listOfCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToList();
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // Consider creating the provider only once!
        var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        // The same is true for the byte array.
        var bytes = new byte[4];

        provider.GetBytes(bytes);
        var number = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        var index = Math.Abs(number % listOfCharacters.Count);

        result.Append(listOfCharacters[index]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

#### Bias testing

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToList();
        var occurences = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        foreach (var character in listOfCharacters)
        {
            occurences.Add(character, 0);
        }

        var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var bytes = new byte[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            provider.GetBytes(bytes);
            var number = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
            var index = Math.Abs(number % listOfCharacters.Count);

            occurences[listOfCharacters[index]]++;
        }

        var orderedOccurences = occurences.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
        var minKvp = orderedOccurences.First();
        var maxKvp = orderedOccurences.Last();

        Console.WriteLine("Min occurence: " + minKvp.Key + " Times: " + minKvp.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Max occurence: " + maxKvp.Key + " Times: " + maxKvp.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Difference: " + (maxKvp.Value - minKvp.Value));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The result is that between the highest occurrence and the lowest is a value somewhere between 700 - 800 which means the bias is somewhere at 0.08% and the two characters with the maximum difference always differs. So i really can't see any bias.

Comment: `% listOfCharacters.Count` creates a bias in the selected item.

Comment: @dtb: I don't think so. Using min or max would do so, but why modulo? It simply reduces the number to an available index and the distribution is the same (based on the available values).

Comment: `number` is a value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 with uniform distribution. `number % listOfCharacters.Count` maps the value to a smaller set of values. Since 4,294,967,296 is not a multiple of `listOfCharacters.Count`, the distribution within the smaller set will not be uniform.

Comment: @dtb: Ok, the bias occurs due to the fact that Count is not a multiple of Int32 range, but this bias will also hit you if you call Random(min, max) cause it has exactly the same problem. Also if you would have absolutely no bias, it would not be completely random anymore.

Comment: No. The value returned by [Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) is uniformly distributed, i.e., it carefully works around this problem. There are questions on StackOverflow where this has been discussed in detailed; my Google foo is too weak right now to provide a good link. A uniform distribution *requires* that the algorithm is not biased towards certain values.

Comment: @dtb: Tested it, by simply replacing the random service provider against random instance (and GetBytes() against NextBytes()) in the above example code. In both cases the min and max are within the same range and the corresponding characters are also changed everytime.

Comment: @dtb: Using ILSpy the `Random(min, max)` does `return (int)(this.Sample() * (double)num) + minValue;`. So a double value will be truncated to an integer, which leads to exactly the same bias problem that my implementation has.

Answer (score 0):

The following program generates ~500 passwords / millisecond on my computer:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var g = new Generator();
        IEnumerable<string> passwords = new List<string>();
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        passwords = g.GetPassword().ToList();
    }
}

class Generator
{
    Random r = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    string randomCharsList;
    const int length = 8;
    const int randomLength = 8000;
    const string listOfCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public Generator()
    {
        CreateRandom();
    }

    private void CreateRandom()
    {
        var randomChars = new StringBuilder();
        string password = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < randomLength + length; i++)
        {
            var random = new Random(i * Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray().First());
            int x = random.Next(0, listOfCharacters.Length);
            randomChars.Append(listOfCharacters[x]);
        }
        randomCharsList = randomChars.ToString();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPassword()
    {
        int pos;
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        while ((DateTime.Now - startTime).Milliseconds < 1)
        {
            pos = r.Next(randomLength);
            yield return randomCharsList.Substring(pos, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a note here about the thread safety issue in generating random numbers (such as a high volume webserver where we ran into this issue).

Essentially, Random class is NOT thread safe and if collision occurs, it will return 0 (not what i expected) which needless to say can really wreak havoc in your logic :) So if using in a multi-threaded environment then make sure to protect access to any shared Random objects.

See section on the 'The System.Random class and thread safety' at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx for more details.

Hope this helps someone.